# Magento 2.3 adds white stripes while resizing a product image for a frontend product list

Tags: magento2

I have installed clean Magento EE2.3 . after I have moved to production mode I got 2 big problems.

1)  when I look on the product page I can see it being resized to a different size with white lines. look at the original image that has been uploaded:

this is cache images:

https://babybeddingdesign.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/b3b166914d87ce343d4dc5ec5117b502/d/u/...

this is original images that were upload (just remove cache):

https://babybeddingdesign.com/pub/media/catalog/product/d/u/dumbo_bedding_set.jpg

2) on Magento EE2.3 when a buyer goto checkout without been register Magento gives a message of 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for Problem 1:**

> White border issue

After creating a plugin to convert the string value to an integer (which properly casts to a boolean), the image frame is not added. For details see this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4622

```
public function beforeSetKeepFrame($image, $keep)
{
    if (is_string($keep)) {
        $keep = (strtolower($keep) === 'true') ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return [$keep];
}
```

> For Resize issue:

In `etc/view.xml` of your current theme, you can update product image size.Make sure you resize with the expect ratio.Use additional tag `<frame>` to prevent white borders on image. 
Example Code:

```
<image id="product_page_main_image" type="small_image">
    <width>460</width>
    <height>460</height>
    <aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
    <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

Check all other tags, not just a tag with the id `product_page_main_image` check others too.

**Solution for Problem 2:**

Go to `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Customers > Reward Points`

[image]

[image]

You may disable the reward functionality do whatever configuration you want to do like display on store front, reward point expiry calculation etc.

Reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/configuration/customers/reward-points.html

**I hope this will help**

Comment: 1) will try and see if this fix it.

Comment: 2) it is enable but not show on front end.

Comment: @schnitz have you tried my solution?

Comment: no this have not help.I try to fix it by changing the etc/view.xml file but same problom. to fix it i have copy all images from /pub/media/catalog/product/ TO /pub/media/catalog/product/cache/b3b166914d87ce343d4dc5ec5117b502/
same location the images show on . This have fix the problem BUT after 24H images go back to same size with the white frame. 

Can you understand what making it ? how it can be that after 1 day the cache images change back again?